# Cargar autoload de PHP sin required

Tags: php, composer

Existe alguna forma de cargar en todos los archivos de mi proyecto php con composer el autoload sin colocar la línea explícita al inicio de cada archivo `require 'vendor/autoload.php'`, es decir que automáticamente con alguna instrucción al crear un nuevo archivo en mi proyecto ya cargue el autoload sin necesidad de hacerle el require, no estoy usando frameworks ni nada solo un proyecto php con composer

Comment: si tu arquitectura fuese https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application si se puede por que asi solo en el index debes cargar el autoload; luego donde implementes si es una clase puede usar USE Namespace/of/Librery. o llamas al objeto: $email = new /phpmailer/phpmailer()

Comment: Autoload existe para evitar tener que hacer con todos los demás archivos lo que ahora quieres hacer con él. Eso no es posible. Lo que estás pidiendo es una especie de AutoAutoLoad al cual tendrás que incluir para evitar incluir a AutoLoad, y si mañana quieres evitar a AutoAutoLoad, tendrás que inventar un AutoAutoAutoLoad que evite llamar a AutoAutoLoad que llama a AutoLoad. Que yo sepa esto no existe, ni tendría sentido que existe. Si quieres AutoLoad tienes que requerirlo, como se ha hecho siempre, con `import` por ejemplo, en otros lenguajes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongamos que tu proyecto sigue la lógica en que un script se mapea a un feature. Por ejemplo, para enviar correos harías un script `mail.php` donde dice algo como

```
<?php

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Swift_SmtpTransport;
use Swift_Mailer;
use Swift_Message;


if(isset($_POST['usermail'],$_POST['content'], $_POST['subject'])) {
  $transport = new Swift_SmtpTransport(...variables);
  $mailer  = new Swift_Mailer($transport);   
  $message = new Swift_Message($subject);

  $message->setFrom($_POST['usermail'])
           ->setBody($_POST['content'])
           ->setSubject($_POST['subject'])
           ->setTo('contacto@misitio.com');

  $mailer->send($message);
}
```

Con ese enfoque cada uno de esos scripts se vuelve un entrypoint. Cada entrypoint necesita meter el autoloader directamente o a través de un archivo de boilerplate que lo haya incluido o requerido. Es tedioso, como habrás visto, y es complejo de mantener. Si quieres añadir una verificación de que el usuario está logueado, tienes que copiar esa verificación en cada entrypoint. En alguno se te puede olvidar y en otro repetirse.

**Lo que debes hacer, en mi opinión, es reducir los entrypoints de tu aplicación, ojalá a uno solo.**

#### Un entrypoint para rutear a lo bestia

La manera más simple de hacerlo (**pero no lo hagas, por favor**) es que una petición que quieras mandar a `mail.php` la mandes en cambio a `index.php?action=mail`, y dentro del `index.php`, que es el único donde necesitas requerir al autoloader, uses el parámetro action para definir si debes incluir `mail.php`, `table.php`, `profile.php`, etc. (**los cuales ya no incluyen explícitamente al autoloader**)

```
<?php 

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

if(isset($_GET['action']) && $action = $_GET['action']) {
    
      switch ($action) {
           case 'mail':
              require 'mail.php';
              break;

           case 'table':
              require 'table.php';
              break;
           default:
              echo 'acción desconocida';
      }
}
```

Obviamente lo primero que hará un usuario malintencionado es mandar algo como `index.php?action=../../../etc/passwd` y terminará ingeniándoselas para hacer un path transversal attack. Sin embargo explico esto porque  bien o mal es una manera de manejar un único entrypoint.

#### Si encapsulamos la ejecución en funciones:

Pensemos ahora que en tu archivo `mail.php` no ejecutas código en el contexto global, sino que declaras una función:

```
<?php

use Swift_SmtpTransport;
use Swift_Mailer;
use Swift_Message;

function sendMail() {
   if(isset($_POST['usermail'],$_POST['content'], $_POST['subject'])) {
      $transport = new Swift_SmtpTransport(...variables);
      $mailer  = new Swift_Mailer($transport);   
      // etc
    }
}
```

Con eso ahora   tu index podría ser:

```
<?php 

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

include __DIR__.'/mail.php';
include __DIR__.'/table.php';

if(isset($_GET['action']) && $action = $_GET['action']) {
    
      switch ($action) {
           case 'mail':
              return sendMail();
              break;

           case 'table':
              return printTable();
              break;
      }
}
```

Pero eso **implica incluir cada script de tus funciones**. Es ineficiente.

#### La Verdadera Solución: OOP

Puedes utilizar clases para manejar tus funcionalidades. En vez de `mail.php` ahora el archivo estará en  `app/MailController.php` (ya con el nombre suena más respetable) y dentro de él se declara una clase. Convertir una función en un método estático es inmediato:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Swift_SmtpTransport;
use Swift_Mailer;
use Swift_Message;

class MailController {

    public static function sendMail() {
       if(isset($_POST['usermail'], $_POST['content'], $_POST['subject'])) {
          $transport = new Swift_SmtpTransport(...variables);
          // etc
        }
    }
}
```

y en el index la invocarías como `MailController::sendMail()`. ¿Por qué digo que esta es la verdadera solución a tu problema?. Yo lo expresaría como: **en vez de tener que incluir el autoloader en todos lados, haz que el autoloader te incluya a ti**. Es su trabajo y lo hace impecablemente. Para este propósito declaras, en tu   *composer.json*

```
"autoload": {
     psr-4": {
       "App\\": "app/",        
     }
 }
```

Regeneras el autoloader (`composer dumpautoload`) y de ahí en adelante tu `index.php` solamente necesita requerir al autoloader (y es el único que necesita hacerlo). Para todo lo demás, puedes invocar directamente tus clases

```
<?php 

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

if(isset($_GET['action']) && $action = $_GET['action']) {
    
      switch ($action) {
           case 'mail':
              return App\MailController::sendMail();
              break;

           case 'table':
              return App\TableController::printTable();
              break;
      }
}
```

El autoloader ya sabe que el namespace `App` apunta al directorio `app`, luego sabe que al ver `App\TableController` debe incluir `app/TableController.php`.

#### La manera elegante de hacerlo

Puedes implementar una lógica de ruteo tal que si (por ejemplo) quisieras dibujar una tabla, no llamarías a `/index.php?action=table` sino a `/table`.

Mediante una simple regla de reescritura en tu webserver, la llamada a `/table`, que no existe como archivo, será delegada a `/index.php`, en donde ya no hay un switch sino un conjunto de rutas que manejas con un paquete como [PHPRoute](https://packagist.org/packages/phroute/phroute)

```
<?php 

use Phroute\Phroute\RouteCollector;

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$router = new RouteCollector();

$router->get('/table', function(){
    return App\TableController::printTable();
});

$router->get('/mail', function(){
    return App\MailController::sendMail();
});  

$router->get('/profile/{user_id:\d+}', function($user_id){
    return App\UserController::displayProfile($user_id);    
});
```

Finalmente, los frameworks implementan la abstracción del request para que no necesites usar las superglobales como `$_POST` o `$_GET`. Pero creo que con lo explicado ya tienes una idea del camino para ordenar tu proyecto.

Comment: Excelente amigo muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Para realizar la carga del autoload de composer lo único que debes hacer es lo que ya hiciste:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php'
```

Esto carga todo el proyecto y no es necesario cargar nada más para que funcione.

Si puede pasar que librerías como phpmailer requieran sumar clases, por ejemplo

```
// Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
```

Te recomiendo el uso de USE para alivianar el tema de los paths que son algo extensos en composer. Para usarlo ir a [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.namespaces.importing.php)

Ojalá esta información sea de utilidad.