# Problema con namespaces en php

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente directorio dentro del proyecto pruebanamespaces:

```
\---app
    +---controllers
    |       Clase3.php
    |
    \---models
            Clase1.php
```

La `Clase1` con su namespace:

```
    <?php
    namespace models;

    class Clase1{

        private $saludo;

        public function __construct(){
            $this->saludo = "Hola desde app/models";
        }

        function getSaludo(){
            return $this->saludo;
        }

        function setSaludo(string $saludo){
            $this->saludo = $saludo;
        }

    }
```

La `Clase3` con su namespace:

```
    <?php
    namespace controllers;

    class Clase3{

        private $saludo;

        public function __construct(){
            $this->saludo = "Hola desde app/controllers";
        }

        function getSaludo(){
            return $this->saludo;
        }

        function setSaludo(string $saludo){
            $this->saludo = $saludo;
        }

    }
```

El archivo `index.php` desde donde los llamo:

```
    <body>
        <?php
            use models\Clase1;
            use controllers\Clase3;

            $clase1 = new Clase1();
            $clase3 = new Clase3();

            echo $clase1->getSaludo() . "<br>";
            echo $clase3->getSaludo() . "<br>";
        ?>
    </body>
```

Y me arroja error continuamente, he intentado probar de mil maneras distintas pero el resultado siempre es que no encuentra la clase.

El error es éste:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'models\Clase1' not found in C:\wamp64\www\pruebaNamespaces\index.php on line 14
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: si añado los requires con la ruta completa de cada archivo si que me funciona, pero entonces no me sirven de nada los namespaces

Comment: ¿Y para que sirve la sentencia use? Ya puedo poner use app\model; por ejemplo, pero luego me da fallo al hacer require_once("Clase1");

Comment: Necesitas un manifiesto de composer para que te genere un `autoload.php`, y tu a la vez requerir ese autoload en el script que procesa el request (en este caso el index). Si no tienes eso, entonces efectivamente tienes que aplicar include o require a mano. Mira [esta respuesa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/428912/cargar-autoload-de-php-sin-required/429202#429202) que tiene algunas ideas. @BetaM en realidad no hay problema con declarar `use A\B\C;`  Eso solamente declara un alias que permite llamar a la clase o función directamente, pero no se evalúa hasta que se intenta invocar.

Answer (score 2):

Esta respuesta indica cómo usar la herramienta [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) para manejar tus dependencias y generar un script de autoload para tu proyecto. Lo ideal es que ese proyecto se estructure de manera de tener un único script (en este caso el index.php) donde se hace el `require` o `require_once` del autoloader y no tener que ponerlo por todas partes.

En la respuesta [Cargar autoload de PHP sin required](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/428912/cargar-autoload-de-php-sin-required/429202#429202) dejé una recomendación de estructura para no terminar requiriendo el autoloader en todos lados, y en esta en cambio me limito a sugerir cómo generarlo.

Dicho esto, estábamos hablando de usar la herramienta [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) para manejar tus dependencias. Tendrías en la raíz de tu proyecto un archivo `composer.json` que diría algo como:

```
{
    "name": "diego_garcia/prueba",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "prueba de autoloader",

    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2|^8.0",
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "ext-mbstring": "*",
        "ext-redis": "*",
        "ext-soap": "*",
        "ext-xml": "*",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.173",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^3.0"
    }
}
```

Y al hacer `composer install` descargaría las dependencias (aws sdk y doctrine en este ejemplo), y las dejaría en una carpeta `C:\wamp64\www\pruebaNamespaces\vendor`. En esa carpeta dejará un archivo `autoload.php` que será lo único que necesitas requerir en tu entrypoint `index.php`.

Composer también revisaría que tengas la versión de php con las extensiones declaradas como necesarias, pero no es lo que nos convoca.

Así como el autoloader genera una lógica para ubicar tus dependencias mapeándolas a su namespace, tu aplicación puede manejarse igual, usando la entrada "autoload" del manifiesto:

```
{
    "name": "diego_garcia/prueba",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "prueba de autoloader",

    "require": {
        ...
    },

    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "models\\": "app/models/",
            "controllers\\": "app/controllers/"
        }
    }
}
```

Con eso el comando `composer install` incluirá tus clases en el autoloader. (y `composer dumpautoload` específicamente regenera el autoload sin los otros pasos).

Por si a alguien le interesa entender cómo opera ese autoloader mágico, se usa  la función [spl_autoload_register](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) para establecer una estrategia de resolución tal que un namespace corresponda a una ruta de archivo. Composer además permite que declares en tu autoload un listado de archivos para incluir en duro.

```
   "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "app/models/Clase1.php",
            "app/controllers/Clase3.php"
        ]
    }
```

Que es más sencillo de entender pero -en proyectos que no sean prueba de concepto- es ineficiente y contamina el scope global con funciones y clases que a lo mejor ni se usan.

Con todo esto en marcha, en tu index ahora podrías poner

```
<?php

    use models\Clase1;
    use controllers\Clase3;

    require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';


    $clase1 = new Clase1();
    $clase3 = new Clase3();

    echo '<body>';
    echo $clase1->getSaludo() . '<br>';
    echo $clase3->getSaludo() . '<br>';
    echo '</body>';
```

Nótese que empiezo el script con `<?php` y deliberadamente no hay tag de cierre. Te ahorrará más de un dolor de cabeza.

Si el lector no quiere usar composer para una simple prueba de concepto, [también se puede escribir un autoloader artesanal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830917/how-do-i-use-php-namespaces-with-autoload) como se hacía hace 10 años. Pero eso es reinventar la rueda.

Answer (score 1):

Según la [documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.namespaces.importing.php), la palabra reservada `use` es -entre otras cosas- para importar/apodar, pero "importar" no en un sentido de *cargar* código, sino de *referir* hacia un *Nombre Completamente Calificado*.

No obstante, puedes habilitar la carga automática de clases con unas cuantas líneas de código:

```
<?php
   function __autoload($class){
      require str_replace('\\', '/', $class).'.php';
   }

   use models\Clase1;
   $clase1 = new Clase1();

   $clase3 = new \controllers\Clase3();

   echo $clase1->getSaludo() . "<br>";
   echo $clase3->getSaludo() . "<br>";
?>
```