# Replicar estructura de función de Laravel para Rutas(API) solo con PHP

Tags: php, laravel, api, clase-abstracta

Estoy tratando de replicar la función que trae laravel para las rutas(API) con solo PHP;
Pero no se me ocurre como podría hacer este tipo de función, Ya que `Route` es una clase y `middleware` una función estática de esta pero luego aparece `->get('/route/', function() {} )` como si estuviera accediendo al metodo de un objeto, Alguien que me explique como podria hacerlo.? soy nuevo en php. Aqui les dejo la Imagen para que entiendan mejor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Se podría hacer eso con solo PHP? o laravel usa otras cosas mas.?

Comment: no es facil, laavel es un framewrok complejo y tiene muchisimas clases, si quieres algo parecido puedes usar slim php

Comment: Si eso supuse, entonces solamente con php no se puede replicar la estructura de la funcion verdad?, Ya que `Route::middleware` Al parecer es una funcion pero luego pone `->get()` y me hace pensar si middleware es una funcion o un objeto o no se de que forma podria hacer eso

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres hacer un router a mano, sin incorporar un framework como Laravel, claro que se puede. Debieras buscar la implementación más minimalista de ruteo para PHP que tenga un mínimo de prestigio o reconocimiento, dado que por cada solución validada por la comunidad hay otras 100 que son malos ejemplos.

[En esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/428912/cargar-autoload-de-php-sin-required/429202#429202) señalé el uso de [PHPRoute](https://packagist.org/packages/phroute/phroute) como un ejemplo mínimo. En él se instancia explícitamente el objeto `$router` y sobre él se van declarando los handlers:

```
<?php 

use Phroute\Phroute\RouteCollector;

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$router = new RouteCollector();

$router->get('/table', function(){
    return App\TableController::printTable();
});

$router->get('/mail', function(){
    return App\MailController::sendMail();
});  

$router->get('/profile/{user_id:\d+}', function($user_id){
    return App\UserController::displayProfile($user_id);    
});
```

Esto no funcionaría si llamas al script por línea de comando, sino que cobra sentido cuando se llama mediante un request. Las características del request son accesibles mediante [superglobales](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) y la instancia de `$router` las lee para compararlas en secuencia (considerando el método, GET, POST, etc) y el path (en este caso, `/table`, `/mail`, etc).

Probablemente no tiene mucho caso entrar a explicar las corrientes submarinas que transitan en las profundidades de Laravel, pero en tu pregunta me parece ver cierto espíritu científico y eso debe ser estimulado. Aquí va mi ensayo sobre el ruteo en Laravel.

##### El ruteo en Laravel

A diferencia del ejemplo anterior, en Laravel el ciclo de vida de un request pasa por un proceso más complejo, el cual facilita su uso pero dificulta su comprensión. En el 99% de los casos nadie se detiene a cuestionar lo que ocurre tras bambalinas, mientras funcione.

Cuando laravel recibe un request, éste entra via `public/index.php`. En ese script se bootea la aplicación y se declara al Kernel como handler de los requests.

```
$app = require_once __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap/app.php';

$kernel = $app->make(Kernel::class);

$response = tap($kernel->handle(
    $request = Request::capture()
))->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Esa variable `$app` es la instancia del Container, la piedra angular del Laravel. Éste implementa la interfaz `ContainerInterface` ([PSR-11](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-11/)) y actúa como contenedor de dependencias y localizador de recursos. Sabe dónde está todo y a través de él, que es accesible desde todos lados, distintos componentes interactúan entre sí.

¿Cómo hace para saber dónde está todo? Bueno, durante el booteo, el container va tomando conocimiento de las dependencias, primero mediante los archivos de configuración. En `config/app.php` se asocian los  `Facade` que tienen especial protagonismo para esta respuesta. Específicamente, el Facade *Route*, que está en  `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Route.php`. El Container aprende a resolverlo y, en el mismo acto, y recíprocamente, el Facade aprende cómo acceder a la instancia de la app.

Ese Router Facade no es el verdadero Router (que está en `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php`). Es sólo un intermediario.

**No tiene sentido intentar replicar el ruteo de Laravel sin replicar el papel del contenedor, puesto que sin el contenedor los Facades no sabrían resolver el objeto al que supuestamente dan acceso.**  Invocar directamente a un archivo de rutas lo evidenciaría con el clásico error:

```
RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set.
```

##### El misterio de los métodos estáticos y dinámicos

Los Facade permiten operar sobre un objeto subyacente sin tener que instanciarlo a mano.

Tú te preguntabas por la existencia de métodos estáticos y dinámicos. En PHP no se puede invocar un método dinámico como estático, y resulta que los métodos como `get` o `post` del RouteRegistrar son dinámicos. Bueno, ahí entra en acción el Facade. Cuando pones:

```
Route::get('/hola', function(...) { ... });
```

El Facade primero obtiene la instancia de su objeto subyacente, un *RouteRegistrar* y el método, que invocaste como estático, lo invoca ahora como método de instancia.

Cuando se invoca métodos como middleware/prefix/etc, el `RouteRegistrar` se devuelve a sí mismo.

```
// Esto retorna la instancia del RouteRegistrar
Route::middleware(['auth','throttle'], function() { ... })
```

De manera que puedes "encadenar" otros llamados a métodos de la clase

```
Route::middleware(['auth:web'])
    ->prefix('/settings')
    ->group(function (): void {
        Route::post('/', [SettingsController::class, 'store']);
    });
```

Si en cambio la llamada declaró una ruta, devuelve un objeto `Route`. La clase `Route` no tiene los mismos métodos. En particular, no tiene métodos para declarar nuevas rutas, de manera que lo siguiente no es válido:

```
  Route::post('/', [SettingsController::class, 'store'])
       ->get('/profile', [SettingsController::class, 'show']);


  BadMethodCallException: Method Route::get does not exist.
```

Pero sí tiene por ejemplo métodos para darle nombre, restringir el tipo de parámetros, el protocolo al que responde, etc

```
 Route::post('/', [SettingsController::class, 'store'])->name('settings');
```